# Setting table name as a variable for a web database?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, html

I am writing a function that will sit in a external file that creates tables within a web DB. This is all being done with Javascript and HTML 5 local databases. I want to pass in a variable to generate the table name like:

```
mydb.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS **?** (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)', [**DB_Table**]);
});
```

but understand that the question mark can only be used in place of [literals](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#parsing-and-processing-sql-statements) is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to parameterise schema names. If you really need to allow dynamic names, you will have to encode them into a schema name literal manually.

The ANSI SQL format for schema name literals is to surround them in double-quotes, and replace any double-quote character inside the string with a doubled double-quote.

```
var txlit= '"'+tc.replace(/"/g, '""')+'"';
query= 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '+txlit+' (id INTEGER ...)';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some reasons for the limits of sql parameters.

But I think you are facing the **meta programming** issue, so check out the [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).

With [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/), it dons't force you to use it exclusively. It just a String template language for any purpose.

Unfortunately, [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) don't support JavaScript, but I think that the philosophy of it's design is still worth to know.